# removing null values for an array

Tags: java

The code takes input for a user for a name and a second input for a birthday. It can store up to 10 entries both `name` + `birthday` and can be terminated early by entering "ZZZ". I figured out most of the code but the part I can't figure out is if the entries are terminated before 10 then there is a text that says something along the lines of `[adam, john, dave, null, null, null,....]`

```
import java.util.*;
public class BirthdayReminderRedo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name = new String[10];
        String[] birthday = new String[10];
        String[] selectName = new String[100];
        String inputName;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count;

        for(count=0; count < 10; count++){
            System.out.println("Please enter a name or type ZZZ to end name inputs>>");
            inputName = userInput.nextLine();
            if(inputName.equals("ZZZ")){
                while(name.remove(null)){}
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println(name);
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
                break;
            }
            else{
                name[count] = inputName;
            }

            if(count == 10){
                for(int secondCount = 0; secondCount > 0; secondCount++);
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter birthday in the format DD/MM/YYYY>>");
                birthday[count] = userInput.nextLine();
            }

        }
        String dataCheck = null;
        do{
            for(int secondCount = 0; secondCount < 10; secondCount++){
                System.out.println("Please enter a name to get the birthday or enter ZZZ to end program>>");
                userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                dataCheck = userInput.nextLine();
                selectName[secondCount] = dataCheck;
                boolean valid = false;
                if(selectName[secondCount].equals("ZZZ")){
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
                    break;
                }
                for(int thirdCount = 0; thirdCount < 10; thirdCount++){
                    if(selectName[secondCount].equals(name[thirdCount])){
                        System.out.println(birthday[thirdCount]);
                        valid = true;
                    }
                    else if (thirdCount == 9 && !valid){
                        System.out.println("Not a valid name");
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(!"ZZZ".equals(dataCheck));
    }
}
```

Any tips on how I can remove the `null`s from this `println`?

Comment: Or a `HashMap` to link the names to the birthdays

Comment: To me, this code looks overly complex: many loops within loops, useless pieces of code (like the for loop followed by a semicolon). Try to break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: What does `for(int secondCount = 0; secondCount > 0; secondCount++);
        break;` supposed to do? Why a blank loop before the `break`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arrays. Why not utilize [`List`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and instantiate an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) so that you don't have to worry about extra/undefined elements in your collection?

```
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> birthday = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] selectName = new String[100];
String inputName;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int count;

for(count=0; count < 10; count++){
    System.out.println("Please enter a name or type ZZZ to end name inputs>>");
    inputName = userInput.nextLine();
    if(inputName.equals("ZZZ")){
        break;
    }
    else{
        name.add(inputName);
    }

    if(count == 10){ //Sunny - Count will never be 10
        for(int secondCount = 0; secondCount > 0; secondCount++);
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please enter birthday in the format DD/MM/YYYY>>");
        birthday.add(userInput.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it. Im still new to java and I couldn't get this to work (user error on my part) but I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using arrays than you either:

1. Copy the values to a new array initialized to the number of inputs, if you want to use Arrays.toString.
2. If you don’t care for using that method, you can also print them as follows:

   ```
    for(String n: name) 
    { 
       if(n!=null)  
           System.out.print(n + " "); 
    }
   ```

If using arrays is not important, do as the other answer suggests; use ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you. I am still trying figure out how to get this to work in my code. I am still new to java so I get mixed up quite a bit.

Comment: @cdroysden I am sorry while editing my answer I made a mistake. In the print statement it should say n, not “name”. I have corrected this.

Comment: thank you! I didn't catch that. It works extremely well

Comment: @cdroysden if my answer helped you, it would be great if you could accept it :)